# Execute an External JAR

Tags: java, jar, external

I wrote a launcher for my game that, when given a valid username and password, will download a JAR file from a website if the file does not already exist or an update is available. The login system and file download work, but how do I run the downloaded JAR file?

I have tried `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar " + file.getAbsolutePath());`, but to no avail.

Thanks for the help!

---

```
downloading = new JLabel("Download AudioRPG executable from server. This may take up to a minute.");
                            downloading.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

                            Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    remove(username);
                                    remove(password);
                                    remove(submit);
                                    remove(remember);
                                    add(downloading, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                                    pack();

                                    try {
                                        FTPClient client = new FTPClient();

                                        client.connect("audiorpg.net");
                                        client.login("audiorpg", "mcpogotime1");
                                        client.changeDirectory("files");
                                        client.download("AudioRPG.jar", exe);
                                        client.disconnect(true);
                                        downloading.setText("Done! Launching AudioRPG...");
                                    }
                                    catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
                                }
                            });

                            th.start();

                            startExternalJAR(getClass(), th, exe);
```

---

```
private static void startExternalJAR(Class<?> c, Thread th, File exe) {
        if (!th.isAlive()) {
            try {
                final String mainClass;
                final JarFile jarFile = new JarFile(exe);
                try {
                    final Manifest manifest = jarFile.getManifest();
                    mainClass = manifest.getMainAttributes().getValue("Main-Class");
                } finally {
                    jarFile.close();
                }
                final URLClassLoader child = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{exe.toURI().toURL()}, c.getClassLoader());
                final Class<?> classToLoad = Class.forName(mainClass, true, child);
                final Method method = classToLoad.getDeclaredMethod("main", String[].class);
                final Object[] arguments = {new String[0]};
                method.invoke(null, arguments);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
        }
        else {
            try { Thread.sleep(1000); }
            catch (Exception e) { }
            startExternalJAR(c, th, exe);
        }
    }
```

That is the code I am attempting to use now, but it is not working. @Boris the Spider any tips?

Comment: Why not classload it and run it internally? Otherwise always use the `String[]` method and split the parameters up, consider using a `ProcessBuilder`.

Answer (score 4):

Don't execute the jar like a command. Load the class you want from the jar using the classloader and then instantiate it.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/jarclassloader.html

1. Load the jar by constructing a `new JarClassLoader("url goes here")`.
2. Call `.invokeClass("MyMainClassName", new String[] { "Args", "Go", "Here" })` on the JarClassLoader.

Comment: "instantiate it" is a little misleading. Calling the `main` method of the downloaded jar is what he wants.

Comment: Is the JarClassLoader class built into Java or is it in a separate library?

Comment: @PogoStick29 yes, JarClassloader is a built in class

Comment: I don't think JarClassLoader is a built-in class, I can't find it anywhere in the Java documentation: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=+jarclassloader+javadoc (usually doing any class name plus the "javadoc" turns it up as a first result if it's in the Java API).

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `URLClassLoader` to load the `jar` and then call `main`.

```
final String mainClass;
final JarFile jarFile = new JarFile(file);
try {
    final Manifest manifest = jarFile.getManifest();
    mainClass = manifest.getMainAttributes().getValue("Main-Class");
} finally {
    jarFile.close();
}
final URLClassLoader child = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{file.toURI().toURL()}, this.getClass().getClassLoader());
final Class classToLoad = Class.forName(mainClass, true, child);
final Method method = classToLoad.getDeclaredMethod("main", String[].class);
final Object[] arguments = {new String[0]};
method.invoke(null, arguments);
```

Taken from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60775/2071828).

Comment: You should try and load the manifest file impossible, to determine the main class

Comment: @Boris the Spider Using your answer, I get the following exception: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: net.audiorpg.audiorpg.AudioRPG.main()`